# Laravel 5 Redirect nothing happend

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5

I use get request to controller function , and redirect to the other website.

I use

```
    return Redirect::away('https://www.google.com');
    return Redirect::refresh('https://www.google.com');
    return Redirect::to('https://www.google.com');
    return redirect->away('https://www.google.com');
    return redirect->to('https://www.google.com');
```

but it's nothing happend ...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: i don't think this is possible. you only get redirected within your app.

Comment: yes , it dose . and I echo some word before return the page got these word... but not redirect... why?

Comment: Umm, it's possible...   In the function I only return  a redirect...   These code just saying what I tried...

Comment: oh yeah. this is possible. sorry i'm wrong. this one work for me. return redirect()->away('https://www.google.com');. are you doing the redirect in json request?

Comment: sorry , I don't know what you mean . I think my laravel just return a response to the browser and redirect .. I didn't use any json request?

Comment: so it's a normal get or post request. not an json(ajax) call. can you post your code. there might be some issues why it's not redirecting. do you get any error?

Comment: yes ,it's a normal get request.  here is my code  ` public function test() { 
return Redirect::to('https://www.google.com');
}`

Comment: did you try to debug your code. check if test method is called? the issue might be in your route. may be it's not wired to that method.

Comment: yeah  i tried echo before return and the pge got the echo ... so i'm sure the method is called.

Comment: so what happened after the method gets called. does it give a blank page or something?

Comment: yes it give a blank page.

Comment: I got point ... the method is thought another method called ... if i move to the same method , its worked... why?

Comment: check your route. and also your controller.

Comment: my route and my controller is simple not special..